# Postix - characters not supported by RFC in the sender or reception

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have the following case.
I need to drop messages on the postfix already during a call if there are characters not supported by RFC in the sender or reception (łąńęćżź, etc). Unfortunately my next hop can't handle such emails and I'd like to whisk them on the connection itself.

For example, "m.wróbel@domen.com", I would like to reject such an email address.

Have you met with something like that?

Comment: You will just throw away everyone's email even though they are perfectly valid?

Comment: Maybe if you describe in more detail what made you believe your nexthop *can't handle such emails* (as opposed to, say, your configuration leading to some error in relaying them correctly) that can be resolved instead?

Comment: My next hop is fidelis and I have confirmation from their support that such messages are not supported.